# How to install steam games on other partition

Tags: 14.04

I've Ubuntu along side windows with 60gb of root and 4gb of home partition. All the other partitions are in NTFS format.

Comment: Why would you do it like it? Applications only should go into /, not steam files. I would suggest give your / partition 15-20GB and rest to home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 128 SSD and a 1TB HDD on my laptop. What I do is I keep / as 30 GB and remaining as my /home partition. And I have auto mounted the 1TB HDD. I have tons of games and I wouldn't want my games to fill up my limited SSD.

So, what I did is:

- Open steam
- View > Settings
- "Downloads" inside Settings
- You will see "Steam Library Folder" open it.
- "Add Library Folder" inside that option and add on your folder/HDD partition you want.
- ????
- Profit

Comment: Tried it already didn't didnt work. But after for reserch i found a thread and it worked for me. Thanks for the replay though. Heres the link - http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864969481983128260/